# Having vertex labels outside of a polygon unlike having all on the same side of the vertices

Tags: qgis, polygon, labeling, layouts, dynamic-text

I would like to have the labels of the vertices stand on the outside of a polygon. In the diagram attached, A and D are on the right side of the vertices but I want them to appear on the left side of the vertices like B and C. Can I have this done automatically?

[image: Image showing polygon with labels from A to D]

Comment: How did you get that result? (Which options did you use in "Placement" tab?)